# Вопрос про работу с асинхронностью

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = []

function ooo(){
    // делаем какой то асинхронный запрос куда то
    .then((res) => {
        res.forEach((i) => {
            arr.one = i[0]
            arr.two = i[1]
        })
    })
}

ooo()


console.log(arr)
```

я делаю в функции какой запрос, парсю ответ и добавляю его в массив, но когда из вне вывожу этот массив в консоль - там пустота. Как сделать так, чтобы там были нужные данные?

Comment: ща придёт золотой молот и сразу зарубит вопрос %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нет, у меня вопрос про другое, если я сделаю console.log(arr) внутри функции- все работает, а если извне - то там пустой массив в консоль выводится.

Comment: Нет, у вас вопрос именно про то

Comment: Это на столько христоматийный вопрос, что его задают не меньше раза в день. Так что мы такие вопросы уже знаем)